# Tagging and recursively create new folders with SVN via commandline

Tags: svn

I have the need of automating SVN nightly tags using a Windows batch file and CLI SVN.

Currently, using Tortoise as GUI, I found that when I need to tag several projects into a newly created folder (with a specific structure) I have to first create all the directory tree and tag each project into it. I found that Subclipse, fortunately, is able not only to tag multiple projects at the same time (possibly firing multiple copy commands), but also to create any missing folder.

Is there a way to do the same with CLI client? Ie. some known switch to add to the command? If not, how to create a directory on the remote repository?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn add --depth=infinity --force *
```

should add everything in a subdir. You then commit. Easy as that.

If you want to do this directly to a remote repo, you're stuck. Whilst you can create a new directory to the repository directly, there's no way to batch several such creates in a transaction. If you need to do this, really, the answer is to use your working copy as a temp area and then commit everything in 1 go.

If you are using a repo over http then you could try to sniff the network, or see the server log to see what commands were executed by subclipse.

Comment: After what you said, it looks obvious that Subclipse is smart enough to first check if branch is feasible (tree exists) and if not send proper directory create commands. The problem is that the same is achievable through Tortoise if I use the repo-browser, without using working copy. Since I need to tag (and carry merge-info) a certain time-specific revision of many projects, it's not the best idea to use the working copy, and using svn add is really bad :) Thanks anyway

Comment: np but I think you might want to look at the question and make it a little clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: I didn't mention Subclipse in the question because I didn't use it often. But it's one of the tools I am able to use at the time. Thank you for the comment!